# If access to database itself is thread safe, how do we assure that redundant data access application instances work thread safely in Java?

Tags: java, cloud, microservices, distributed

In today's cloud native applications that access data storage we usually have many instances of same program that we want to be a reliable source of data. How do we make sure those applications supply valid data despite client requests are being processed in instances that belong to separate jar files?

For example:

We have reduntant instances of service WithdrawMoneyService that withdraws amount from a bank account. How do we assure these instances do not mistankely withdraw money twice?

PS Please inform me if it is wrong place to ask this type of questions.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. What have different jar-files to do with it? Why is the access to the database relevant? What about other data sources (e.g. file systems, or other web-systems)? An answer from a system is, of course, only a snapshot of the current state of the system.

Comment: We have reduntant instances of service X that withdraws amount from a bank account. How do we assure these instances do not mistankely withdraw money twice?

Comment: Why should they? If it is a web request, the request is forwarded to one system, and one system only. If it is a message, then the message is processed by one system, and one system only (provided, the messaging system and the clients are correctly configured). One can make such an argument for (almost) all systems.

Comment: Hm so there such use case in real life when we must acquire an external lock?

Comment: There surely are. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because I reackon how can I implement it in Java for my needs. What is the name of the framework/solution?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206171/discussion-between-sinny-and-turing85).